# The best way to filter down a dataSet with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The idea was to query a dataset with querystring params. I only want the "records" to match only what was queried.

Dataset

```
{
 1111:
 {
 Category: "Education"
 Role: "Analyst"
 }
 2222:
 {
 Category: "Communications and Media"
 Role: "Analyst"
 }
 3333:
 {
 Category: "Public Sector"
 Role: "Something else"
 }
 4444:
 {
 Category: "Public Sector"
 Role: "Something else"
 }
...
}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I'm sending in qString

```
Category: (2) ['Communications and Media', 'Education']
Role: ['Analyst']
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I'd like to loop over that and filter/reduce so I only have records that match. Sort of an `and` instead of an `or`.

dataSet is an Object of objects. Thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
export const Filtered = (qStrings, dataSet) => {
  const filtered = [];
  Object.entries(qStrings).forEach(([field]) => {
    qStrings[field].forEach((value) => {
      filtered.push(
        ..._.filter(dataSet, (sess) => {
          if (sess[field] && sess[field].toString() === value.toString()) {
            return sess;
          }
        })
      );
    });
  });
  return _.uniq(filtered);
};
```

Comment: What is an example of dataset and what would be the expected outcome of your function?

Comment: @windowsill There's somewhat of a dataset example. I would like only the records that match the dynamic fields specified together returned -- sort of a dynamic "&&".

Comment: Altho this gives me the same outcome, this look cleaner. 

```
export const Filtered = (qStrings, dataSet) => {
  const filtered = [];
  for (const key in qStrings) {
    filtered.push(
      ..._.filter(dataSet, (sess) => {
        return qStrings[key].includes(sess[key]);
      })
    );
  }
  console.log(filtered);
  return _.uniq(filtered);
};
```

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with what you've tried?? Please include the appropriate data, expected outcome, your attempts, and actual outcome when you post a question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @windowsill ok -- I'm working on it. I want to return the records that match all the filters. Thanks for responding. Something like with every loop, I'm taking a subset until, I only have the records selected.

Answer (score 0):

geez, I figured it out with a colleague who's way smarter than me *wink* Jess!

```
export const Filtered = (qStrings, dataSet) => {
  let filtered = [];

  Object.entries(qStrings).forEach(([field], idx) => {
    let source = filtered;
    if (idx === 0) {
      source = dataSet;
    }
    filtered = _.filter(source, (sess) => {
      return sess[field] && sess[field].includes(qStrings[field]);
    });
  });
  return _.uniq(filtered);
};
```

Now to clean this up.

Comment: What is it about solution that actually solves your problem? What was the original problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem exactly, but you can apply this logic without mutation for a much cleaner function.

```
export const matches = (qStrings, dataSet) =>
  Object.entries(dataSet).reduce((acc, [key, value]) =>
    Object.entries(value).every(([rKey, rValue]) => qStrings[rKey]?.includes(rValue))
      ? { ...acc, [key]: value }
      : acc,
    {});
```

This will return records 1111 and 2222 because they match one of the categories and the role in qStrings.